# How to tag location (manually) in Google Maps using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, location

I have an Android Studio application that uses Google Maps, wherein I want to implement a "tag your location". What I want to happen is, the user could tag/input his location in google maps so other users could find his location.

For example, I am a stall owner and I want to input my location in a specific part of the market place so people could find directions to my stall.

Is there a way how to do that? And if yes, help me how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Here is my MapsActivity.java code:

```
package com.example.kliwa_000.sholocoo;


import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import Modules.DirectionFinder;
import Modules.DirectionFinderListener;
import Modules.Route;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements     OnMapReadyCallback, DirectionFinderListener{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private EditText destination, origin;
    private Button btnFind;
    private List<Marker> originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Marker> destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Polyline> polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    int PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 10000;
    double latitude, longitude;
    double end_latitude, end_longitude;
    public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null){
            if (bundle.get("some") != null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + bundle.get("some"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)     getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        btnFind = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFind);
        destination = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.destination);
        origin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.origin);

        btnFind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendRequest();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendRequest(){

        String Sdestination = destination.getText().toString();
        String Sorigin = origin.getText().toString();

        try{
            new DirectionFinder(this, Sorigin, Sdestination).execute();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap(){
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }

    private void handleNewLocation(Location location){
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(200);
        mMap.moveCamera(zoom);
        mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);



        LatLng userlocation = new LatLng(0, 0);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]
                        {
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.INTERNET
                        }, 10);
            }
            return;
        }

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
       // mMap.addMarker(new     MarkerOptions().position(userlocation).title("Current Location"));

        /*LatLng seveneleven = new LatLng(16.4088, 120.5978 );
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(seveneleven).title("7/11 Gov. Pack").snippet("Carrots: Php 40/kilo"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(seveneleven));

        LatLng ezzerm = new LatLng(16.4087, 120.5993 );
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ezzerm).title("SM Baguio City").snippet("Carrots: Php 35/kilo"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ezzerm));

        LatLng burnham = new LatLng(16.4093, 120.5950 );
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(burnham).title("Burnham Park").snippet("Carrots: Php 45/kilo"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(burnham));

        LatLng whitehouse = new LatLng(16.477949, 120.502748);*/

    }

    @Override
    public void onDirectionFinderStart() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait.",
            "Finding direction..!", true);

        if (originMarkers != null) {
            for (Marker marker : originMarkers) {
                marker.remove();
            }
        }

        if (destinationMarkers != null) {
            for (Marker marker : destinationMarkers) {
                marker.remove();
            }
        }

        if (polylinePaths != null) {
            for (Polyline polyline:polylinePaths ) {
                polyline.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDirectionFinderSuccess(List<Route> routes) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
        originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
        destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Route route : routes) {
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(route.startLocation, 16));
        ((TextView)     findViewById(R.id.tvDuration)).setText(route.duration.text);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDistance)).setText(route.distance.text);

            originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_blue))
                .title(route.startAddress)
                .position(route.startLocation)));
        destinationMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.end_green))
                .title(route.endAddress)
                .position(route.endLocation)));

            PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().
                    geodesic(true).
                    color(Color.BLUE).
                    width(10);

            for (int i = 0; i < route.points.size(); i++)
                polylineOptions.add(route.points.get(i));

            polylinePaths.add(mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions));
        }
    }
}
```

Honestly, my code is a little bit messy, but I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: Capture the long click event, then add a marker and maybe persist the coordinates somewhere.

Comment: Go the boring route and use the Google Maps app and share the location link using a social channel - then advertise the social channel.